# Get selected item from list view

Tags: android, android-intent

I've done some searching and none of the questions on this forum seem to match mine.

**What I'm trying to accomplish:** 
I have a  **List View**  in my app. When I select and item, I want the app to be able to read what that item is and do what I want it to do accordingly. 
The App I'm making is a text-based RPG game. So for  instance: You enter the shop and you see inside the  **List View**  a "Bronze Helmet" for 100 gold. When you click on the bronze helmet I want it to be able to understand, "User clicked Bronze Helmet, lets minus 100 gold from that users money and give him the helmet"

**What I've tried:**

```
if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(1).toString() == "(100G) Bronze Helmet") {
                int gold Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1.getText().toString()) - 100;
                textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            }
```

Now that works perfectly. But here's a few more lines of code to demonstrate what's happening:

```
if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(2).toString() == "(250G) Bronze Chestplate") {
                int gold = Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1.getText().toString()) - 250;
                textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            }
if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(3).toString() == "(125G) Bronze Leggings") {
                int gold = Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1.getText().toString()) - 125;
                textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            }
if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(4).toString() == "(100G) Bronze Boots") {
                int gold = Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1.getText().toString()) - 100;
                textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            }
```

So now what's happening is: When I click on the "Bronze Helmet" it subtracts not only the 100 gold from the helmet, but also the gold from the Chestplate, Leggings, etc...

**So my question is:**  
How do I get the app to read just one line individually and compare it to the string selected? I also tried the: "getSelectedItem()" but that gives me a nullPointerException.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

```
MeleeArmourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            if (MeleeArmourList.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1) {
                int gold = Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1
                        .getText().toString()) - 100;
                textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: When comparing two strings, you need to use `.equals()` rather than `==`.

Comment: Not true. It's best practice to, but the code will work (in many cases) without it

Comment: @Moshe It sometimes works, but that's largely due to JVM implementation details and identity of string literals. Using `.equals()` is the most dependable method and is the only one that I would recommend.

Comment: Where do you put those code above in? Can you post full activity. I'll add solution.

Comment: Yul - Posted in edit section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `int` argument that's passed to `onItemClick()` is the position of the list item that was clicked, so there's no need to call any other methods to retrieve it.

If I understand your goal correctly, you could use something similar to the following:

```
MeleeArmourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position,
            long item_id) {

        switch(position) {
        case 1:
            // (100G) Bronze Helmet
            int gold = Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1.getText().toString()) - 100;
            textViewShopGoldValue1.setText("" + gold);
            break;
        case 2:
            // (250G) Bronze Chestplate
            ...
            break;
        }
        ...
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

`getItemAtPosition` returns the item associated with that position, independent of whether or not it was selected.

It seems that you would want to set a callback for when an item is selected:
`setOnItemSelectedListener` seems to be the correct way to go for that.

See the docs for [getItemAtPosition](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition%28int%29)and [setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(1).toString() == "(100G) Bronze Helmet"){
}
```

You are  comparing string contents with == operator

try with equals() operator

```
if ("(100G) Bronze Helmet".equals(MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(1).toString() )){
}
```

or

```
 if (MeleeArmourList.getItemAtPosition(1).toString().equals("(100G) Bronze Helmet"))
       {

        }
```

you can check your selected item position using this code

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
      "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
      .show();
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't work. You just reversed the order of the same thing I did. checking if "(100G) Bronze helmet" is equal to the 1st item in the list. Will always be true